# A tool to easily dig into database

Tags: sql-server, database

I use SQL Server in an ASP.NET project on Azure framework.

I constantly find myself querying the production database to find reasons for problems and so. It often takes construction of several complicated queries and hence is quite time consuming.

I was wondering if there is any tool that would let me browse my database by entity after I define for it the connectors between them. Maybe something that looks like this ([a general idea of how it may look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4E9i.png)):

[image]

Comment: you could just save your debugging queries out to a text file then reload when you need.

Comment: I forgot to mention, there is a visual query designer in the View section. If you right click onViews, and choose new view, you can visually design queries there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) will generate result sets that are hierarchical, which appears to be what you want.

Besides allowing you to do this, LinqPad is a heck of a prototyping and scratchpad tool. I consider it to be an essential tool for software and database developers. There used to be a free version. I don't know if there still is.